# Loading saved model trained in an earlier tensorflow version

Tags: tensorflow

I recently use Google AutoML service to create a model.

Its output seems to be in a saved model format. However,when I attempt to load it via `tf.saved_model.load` ,it display following error
`Op type not registered 'TreeEnsembleSerialize' in binary ...`

When I look up this op,I find that this op exists in `tf.contrib.boosted_trees` in Tensorflow 1.15,but since Tensorflow 2 removes tf.contrib,this op has be renamed to `BoostedTreesSerializeEnsemble` in `tf.raw_ops`.

My question is:**Is there any way to duplicate the op and rename it to `TreeEnsembleSerialize` ,so the saved model could be loaded without errors.**

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

There are no significant compatibility concerns for saved models.

1. TensorFlow 1.x saved_models work in TensorFlow 2.x.
2. TensorFlow 2.x
   saved_models work in TensorFlow 1.x if all the ops are supported.

For more information visit [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#saved_models_compatibility)